# Azure EventHubs REST API 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, azure, curl, azure-eventhub, azure-cli

I'm trying to execute eventhubs restapi using curl but it does not work.

**curl**

```
curl --proxy $PROXY -i -X "GET" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/$NAME_SPACE/eventhubs/$EVENTHUB?api-version=2017-04-01" -H "Authorization: $TOKEN"
```

**Generate SAS (C#)**

```
var resourceuri = "https://myspacename.servicebus.windows.net/myeventhub";
            var key = "mykey";
            var keyname = "mykeyname";
            TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
            var expiry = Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + week);

            string stringToSign = Uri.EscapeDataString(resourceuri) + "\n" + expiry;
            HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
            var sasToken = String.Format("SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", Uri.EscapeDataString(resourceuri), Uri.EscapeDataString(signature), expiry, keyname);
            return sasToken;
```

**Response**

```
{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is provided in an invalid format."}}
```

I referred this doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/rest/api/eventhub/Generate-SAS-token?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
Furthermore, I tried to use this tool (https://github.com/sandrinodimattia/RedDog/releases/tag/0.2.0.1) but it was same result, too.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Yes, you're a building a SAS token for `servicebus.windows.net` then calling `management.azure.com`. Which one is it? If it's the latter, use ARMClient to get an access token, Azure AD libraries (ADAL) or straight up OAuth with `curl` against `login.microsoftonline.com`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I don't know which uri is correct now in this case, so I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API(`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/$NAME_SPACE/eventhubs/$EVENTHUB?api-version=2017-04-01`) is an [Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/get). You could get token like below:

```
curl -X "POST" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token" \
-H "Cookie: flight-uxoptin=true; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=productionb; stsservicecookie=ests" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--data-urlencode "client_id=$APPID" \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials" \
--data-urlencode "client_secret=$PASSWORD" \
--data-urlencode "resource=https://management.azure.com/"
```

When you request the API, in the Header, you should use `-H "Authorization: Bearer $token"`. So, you should modify like below:

```
curl --proxy $PROXY -i -X "GET" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/$NAME_SPACE/eventhubs/$EVENTHUB?api-version=2017-04-01" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

Comment: OK, so I did not understand for differences between Azure REST API and REST API which is provided each resource. Then, I should generate oauth2 token if use **Azure REST API**, while I should generate SAS token if use **Azure EventHubs REST API**. Is that correct ?

Comment: The API begin with `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions` is Azure Rest API.  You should use `Bearer ` token.

Comment: The API begin with `https://your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/` is   Event Hubs service REST API, in Header the token is like `Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net&sig=tYu8qdH563Pc96Lky0SFs5PhbGnljF7mLYQwCZmk9M0%3d&se=1403736877&skn=RootManageSharedAccessKey `, you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/event-hubs-runtime-rest).

Comment: I appreciate your explanation in detail.  I review my process.

Comment: Yes, I changed API endpoint to EventHubs REST API so it worked. Thank you for everything !